# tf.losses.log_loss and tf.nn.softmax in Tensorflow and Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, cross-entropy

I am trying to implement a network which has the following loss function definition in Pytorch

```
logits = F.log_softmax(layer_output)
loss = F.nll_loss(logits, labels)
```

This link https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-equivalence-to-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-in-tensorflow/18727 mentions that log_softmax should be used instead of softmax as it is more stable before calculating nll loss

In tensorflow i have the following code

```
logits = tf.nn.log_softmax(layer_output)
loss = .tf.losses.log_loss(logits, labels)
```

This leads to a NAN value in loss from first iteration. If i use tf.nn.softmax I don't have a NAN value. But the link mentions log_loss is more stable. Is there any specific reason for this? I could get rid of the NANs using tf.clip_by_value but that leads to vanishing gradients.

Comment: You could use tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2

This will take in raw logits, put it through softmax and then calculate the cross entropy loss. 

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245113/whats-the-difference-between-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-and-losses-log-l] . If i understand correctly, using log_loss should give better results as it calculates for negative examples as well. I have tried with tf.nn.softmax and then using these logits for log_loss which gives reasonable loss values. But as the original implementation has log_softmax , I am curious as to why that gives me NAN loss values

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong naming convention:

`logits` should go into the `softmax` or `log_softmax` (`log` of `softmax`).

These two lines are equivalent:

```
r = F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(a, -1), p)
r = F.cross_entropy(a, p)
```

What you search is `F.cross_entropy` in PyTorch or

`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in `tf`